# Anchor Tags not working in IE or FF

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox, anchor

My anchor tags aren't working properly in IE or FF. Works fine in Chrome. Help?! Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q55gH/1/) that shows what I'm trying to accomplish and see [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/kHaPAuP5) for raw HTML.

**I didn't know how to import JQuery into JSFiddle, so that's why the PasteBin link is there.**

Basically, I have a grid of people which, whenever hovered over, displays information about the staff member. The anchor tags are the letters of the alphabet toward the top of the page. When clicked, they are supposed to go to the first name that starts with that letter in the grid. This works fine in Chrome, but doesn't move but down to the first row on both Firefox and IE.

This code is being used inside the Spiceworks User portal, so that's why the HTML tags aren't present.

I basically have no idea why this is happening and am wondering if someone can pass some knowledge my way.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!--See links in description above.-->
```

Comment: The left sidebar on JSFiddle called **Frameworks & Extensions** has a dropdown menu that allows you to use any of several JQuery versions. By default it is set to `No library (pure JS)`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @Two-BitAlchemist.  Guess I could have poked around and found that out myself.  Alas, here I am, lazy.  Eating doritos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up anchoring to the picture elements themselves (which already had IDs set) and not using separate a tags.  Will take a bit of upkeep, but at least it looks right.  The non-breaking spaces in the anchor tags created some alignment issues on my page.  Here's the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q55gH/3/) showing what I ended up with.

Thanks for your suggestions, everyone.

---

Instead of this in the grid of pictures:

```
<a id="Aanchor">&nbsp;</a>
```

I went with this in the alpha tags at the top:

```
<a href="#AdamC">A</a>
```

(which linked to the pictures themselves below and not a separate a tag)

Comment: I think this is a wonderfully judicious use of what you already had. Did you know you can accept your own answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try doing your anchors like this:

```
<a id="tips">Useful Tips Section</a>
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

Also there is a very simple effect for transition on your anchor. So when you click the letter at the top it smoothly scrolls down to the picture. Worth the time its a nice effect and wont take long to implement. 
the code and tutorial is - [Here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

you can also [View The Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/)

Comment: See my post below for the route I took.  Don't have high enough rep to give you a +1 @user2515563, but that jquery scroll is pretty slick.  Easy to implement!

Comment: I'll +1 him for you since he went the extra mile and showed you how to do what all the cool kids do when faced with this. :P

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor tags are empty, so some browsers are ignoring them.

Where you have:

```
<a name="Aanchor"></a>
```

You should try instead:

```
<a id="Aanchor">&nbsp;</a>
```

Also, the newer way to do this is using id's, not naming anchors as you have.

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q55gH/1/) where I changed the `#Canchor`. This works for me on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, you need to have text within the anchor tag for it to work correctly. If you don't want anything in the name anchors, you can just use a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

So this:

```
<a name="Aanchor"></a>
```

Becomes this:

```
<a name="Aanchor">&nbsp;</a>
```